# Create multiple VM's in Azure with different nic's

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create two vm's in different locations which have different nic's. This is my code, but I have an error and I don't know why, because this solution is recommended when I compile the code:

```
variable "locations" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    vm1 = "North Europe"
    vm2 = "West Europe"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-nic"
  location            = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}



resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  for_each              = var.locations
  name                  = "${each.key}t-vm"
  location              = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name   = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key]]
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"
...
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on environment.tf line 68, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main":
  68:   network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key]]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_network_interface.main is object with 2 attributes
    | each.key is "vm2"

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_ids": element 0: string
required.
```

Comment: Can you share the variable locations? And if you just want to create multiple VMs in different regions and with NICs?

Comment: I have added this variable.

Comment: Well, if the answer solves your problem, please accept it as the answer so that it could help others who are searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key].id]
```